# Cannot find the object because it does not exist or you do not have permissions. Error in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I have a database and have a Sql script to add some fields to a table called "Products" in the database.

But when i am executing this script, I am getting the following error:

```
Cannot find the object "Products" because it does not exist or you do not have permissions
```

Why is the error occurring and what should I do to resolve it?

Comment: which is ***sql script*** ?

Comment: This may be permissions related. Is the user a member of the db_owner role?

Comment: I found the answer to my case in [another string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1601562/cannot-find-the-object-xxx-because-it-does-not-exist-or-you-do-not-have-permis)

Answer (score 78, accepted):

Are you sure that you are executing the script against the correct database? In SQL Server Management studio you can change the database you are running the query against in a drop-down box on one of the toolbars, or you can start your query with this:

```
USE SomeDatabase
```

Comment: +1 If you are using Azure Synapse and opened a sql script it by default selects "built-in" database, you need to change that to related database (if dedicated pool switch it from menu)

Answer (score 109):

I found a reason why this would happen.  The user had the appropriate permissions, but the stored procedure included a `TRUNCATE` statement:

```
TRUNCATE TableName
```

Since `TRUNCATE` deletes items without logging, you (apparently) need elevated permissions to execute a stored procedure that contains it.  We changed the statement to:

```
DELETE FROM TableName
```

...and the error went away!

Comment: The truncate statement was an issue for me as well.  Adding the proper permissions for truncate fixed it.

Comment: This should be logged as a sql server bug.  The error message is "Cannot  find object x..." but the issue relates to permissions of an object different than x.  No, the error message is not "Cannot find the object x because it does not exist.  Or, you do not have permissions.".  Although that non-existent error message might give a bit more of a clue it is still not as helpful as an error message that indicates the correct object with the permission problem.

Comment: That was exactly my problem - it worked perfectly from my local user, but not using a service-account in the production environment - thanks!

Comment: Fixed my obscure problem too! THANKS!

Comment: Have the DB script out the offending sproc to evaluate. I didn't think this applied to me, but turns out a bug in my script allowed a GRANT EXEC line to be included in the sproc itself that was not supposed to be there. Oy.

Comment: I used Grant Alter on <<your table>> to <<your user>> to allow run truncate  command in my stored proc

Answer (score 17):

It can also happen due to a typo in referencing a table such as `[dbo.Product]` instead of `[dbo].[Product]`.

Comment: worked! had the typo in table name

Comment: I'm scared that you knew the exact typo I made.  : )

Answer (score 9):

Does the user you're executing this script under even see that table??

```
select top 1 * from products
```

Do you get any output for this??

If yes: does this user have the permission to modify the table, i.e. execute DDL scripts like `ALTER TABLE` etc.? Typically, regular users don't have this elevated permissions.

Answer (score 8):

Look for any DDL operation in the script.
Maybe the user does not have access rights to run changes.

In my case it was `SET IDENTITY_INSERT tblTableName ON`

You can either add `db_ddladmin` for the whole database or for just the table to solve this issue (or change the script)

```
-- give the non-ddladmin user INSERT/SELECT as well as ALTER:
GRANT ALTER, INSERT, SELECT ON dbo.tblTableName TO user_name;
```

Answer (score 5):

It could also be possible that you have created the "Products" in your login schema and you were trying to execute the same in a different schema (probably dbo)

Steps to resolve this issue

1)open the management studio 
2) Locate the object in the explorer and identify the schema under which your object is? ( it is the text before your object name ). In the image below its the "dbo" and my object name is action status

[image: highlighted part is schema name]

if you see it like "yourcompanydoamin\yourloginid" then you should 
you can modify the permission on that specific schema and not any other schema.

you may refer to ["Ownership and User-Schema Separation in SQL Server"](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb669061%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Comment: I had to put a line in my database context class so i could access the tables created in my hosting sql server, Wich is: modelBuilder.HasDefaultSchema("userteste");

Answer (score 2):

You can right click the procedure, choose properties and see which permissions are granted to your login ID.  You can then manually check off the "Execute" and alter permission for the proc.

Or to script this it would be:

```
GRANT EXECUTE ON OBJECT::dbo.[PROCNAME]
    TO [ServerInstance\user];

GRANT ALTER ON OBJECT::dbo.[PROCNAME]
    TO [ServerInstance\user];
```

Comment: The procedure is running... the issue is access to the table, not the procedure.

Answer (score 2):

I've been trying to copy a table from PROD to DEV but get an error:
"Cannot find the object X because it does not exist or you do not have permissions."

However, the table did exist, and I was running as sa so I did have permissions.

The problem was actually with CONTRAINTS. I'd renamed the table on DEV to be old_XXX months ago. But when I tried to copy the original one over from PROD, the Defaut Constraint names clashed.

The error message was misleading

Comment: You should add some reproducible code to make your answer easy to understand.

Comment: Sorry, I only use the SSIS GUI. Is there a way to convey this without a bunch of screenshots?

Answer (score 2):

This could be a permission issue. The user needs at least ALTER permission to truncate a table.
Another option is to call DELETE FROM instead of TRUNCATE TABLE, but this operation is slower because it writes to the Log file, whereas TRUNCATE does not write to the log file.

> The minimum permission required is ALTER on table_name. TRUNCATE TABLE
> permissions default to the table owner, members of the sysadmin fixed
> server role, and the db_owner and db_ddladmin fixed database roles,
> and are not transferable. However, you can incorporate the TRUNCATE
> TABLE statement within a module, such as a stored procedure, and grant
> appropriate permissions to the module using the EXECUTE AS clause.

Answer (score 1):

In my case I was running under a different user than the one I was expecting.

My code passed `'DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=...;DATABASE=...;Trusted_Connection=false;User Id=XXX;Password=YYY'` as the connection string to `pypyodbc.connect()`, but it ended up connecting with the credentials of the Windows user that *ran the script* instead of the `User Id=` from the connection string.

*(I verified this using the SQL Server Profiler and by putting an invalid uid/password combination in the connection string - which didn't result in an expected error).*

I decided not to dig into this further, since switching to this better way of connecting fixed the issue:

```
conn = pypyodbc.connect(driver='{SQL Server}', server='servername',
                        database='dbname', uid='userName', pwd='Password')
```

Answer (score 1):

Sharing my case, hope that will help.

In my situation inside `MY_PROJ.Database->MY_PROJ.Database.sqlproj` I had to put this:

```
<Build Include="dbo\Tables\MyTableGeneratingScript.sql" />
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case, someone had added a GRANT permission statement beneath the stored procedure that was saved with and being executed as part of the stored procedure. It was the GRANT statement causing the error.

```
create proc Abc
as
begin
   ...
end
go

grant execute on Abc ...
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case the sql server version on my localhost is higher than that on the production server and hence some new variables were added to the generated script from the localhost. This caused errors in creating the table in the first place.
Since the creation of the table failed, subsequent query on the "NON EXISITING" table also failed.
Luckily, in among the long list of the sql errors, I found this "OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF" to be the new varialbe in the script causing my issue. I did a search and replace and the error went away.
Hope it helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

The TRUNCATE statement was my first problem, glad to find the solution here.  But I was using SSIS and trying to load data from another database, and it failed with the same error on any table that used IDENTITY to create an auto-incrementing ID.  If I was scripting it myself I'd first need to use the command **SET IDENTITY_INSERT *tablename* ON**, and then  **SET IDENTITY_INSERT *tablename* OFF** when the table update was done.  But this requires ALTER permissions on the table, which I do not have.  Hence the error message in SSIS on the table load (even though the previous step had just deleted all the data out of the table.)

Answer (score 0):

You receive this error, when you use an ORM like GORM (https://gorm.io/) in Go for example.

When you try to create a struct and accidentally pass the ID (primary key) although it's inserted automatically.

Rich features IDE like Visual Studio Code make this mistake happen easily:

```
if tx := db.Create(&myStruct{
    Ts:                Time.Now(),
    ID:                42,
}); tx.Error != nil {
    t.Fatal(tx.Error)
}
```

You can still use auto-filling by Visual Studio Code, but delete your entry for your model's primary keys:

```
if tx := db.Create(&myStruct{
    Ts:                Time.Now(),
}); tx.Error != nil {
    t.Fatal(tx.Error)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This error is caused mainly due to incorrect column mapping to a column which has identity insert. So, please make sure to check if you have mapped any source column to a sink where identity insert is enabled. If so, you should ignore that column from mapping else remove identity insert.