# Entity Framework 6: Cannot find the object because it does not exist or you do not have permissions

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

This is probably **not** a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1601562/cannot-find-the-object-xxx-because-it-does-not-exist-or-you-do-not-have-permis).

I've been beating my head against the wall for quite a few hours. I'm trying to use the code-first workflow in EF 6 for an existing database. I've imported all the models and done the first initial migration.

The problem is that after I make the first change and add a new migration, and then run the `update-database` command, I get a stupid error:

> Cannot find the object 'X' (the table name) because it does not exist or you do not have permissions.

And it doesn't matter what table I make changes to, I get this error for every single table.

One thing that I noticed is that when I create a new table (model) instead of making changes to an existing one, I don't get any errors but when I check out the database I don't see the corresponding table, meaning that EF doesn't actually make any changes to the database. It also doesn't create the `dbo._MigrationHistory` table!

I don't really know what to do, I googled this error a thousand times but I don't seem to find the answer.

Thanks.

Comment: It looks like your connection string is pointing to a different database (and/or server), to which you actually don't have permissions, or where said table actually doesn't exist.

Comment: so from my understanding, what basically happens is the migrations is trying to update some table which doesn't exist. can you try setting a new connection string that points to a clean new db, and run the migrations after deleting all of the old ones? also, check your selected project in package manager console and it's respective connection string