# EntityFramework 6.0 CreateDatabaseIfNotExists Code first tries to migrate before creating initial structure

Tags: entity-framework

I had a perfectly working EF6.0 DbContext, which I initialize using code:

```
        using (var db = new MyDbContext())
        {
            db.Database.CreateIfNotExists();
        }
```

I started testing migrations on it today. What I did is: I ran following commands in package manager window:

```
Enable-Migrations –EnableAutomaticMigrations
```

Then I modified one of the classes adding a `public int TestField { get;set; }` property and ran:

```
Add-Migration AddTestId
```

**ADDITION:** Also, I created a static initializer:

```
    static MyDbContext()
    {
        Database.SetInitializer(
            new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<MyDbContext, Configuration>()); 
    }
```

I tried to run a unit test. What it used to do is create a database from scratch (e.g.: database does not exist before unit test). It was using code I initially posted, e.g.: `CreateIfNotExists()`

What I noticed is that unit test now fails with SQL exception `Cannot find the object "dbo.RecordExpirations" because it does not exist or you do not have permissions`.

I ran SQL profiler on the database to see what is being run, and I see following (code cleaned up for simplicity, "go" and "sp_resetconnection" lines removed):

```
select serverproperty('EngineEdition')
SELECT Count(*) FROM sys.databases WHERE [name]=N'MYDBNAME'
create database [MYDBNAME]
if serverproperty('EngineEdition') <> 5 execute 
     sp_executesql N'alter database [MYDBNAME] set read_committed_snapshot on'
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[RecordExpirations] ADD [TestField] [int] NOT NULL DEFAULT 0
drop database [MYDBNAME]
```

Basically what happens is: after `create database` is: EF directly proceeds to running migrations, even though initial structure was never created, so ALTER TABLE fails, since there has not been a table created yet to alter.

I have a feeling I missed a step. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Update-Database? Not sure, just a guess also see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1136628/cannot-find-the-object-because-it-does-not-exist-or-you-do-not-have-permissions

Comment: @twice I didn't mention that I did run Update-Database, however since database in the unit test is created from scratch, I see no reason it could have possibly had any effect

Answer (score 1):

I did some digging and figured out procedure which finally worked out for me. This must be done on the clean project, e.g.: folder `Migrations` should not already be present. If it is - perform rollback in source control, and make sure it's not on disk physically.

Also, it seems that EF is using the database on the server (or localdb), so if you played around with it, might be a good idea to rebuild schema from scratch. In my case, removing it worked because I start from zero.

First things to do:

- Set my db project as startup project (important cuz this is where it takes app.config from)
- Set my db project as default in package manager window

Drop Default Database

- Examine app.config in my db project, make sure there is a valid connection string, and that default constructor for MyDbContext is using it.
- Drop that database

Let package manager do its magic, run following commands:

```
Enable-Migrations –EnableAutomaticMigrations
Add-Migration "Initial"
Update-Database
```

After `Add-Migration "Initial"`, a file must appear in Migrations folder with `public override void Up()` method, which should create the complete schema. If it does not do that, something went wrong.

Answer (score -1):

Use CreateFile,ReadFile,WriteFile for storage data in database instead unsign function SQL (which is complex and hardest).
For c# use StreamWriter,BinaryWriter,StreamReader,BinaryReader instead EntityFrameWork (which is very complex and difficult !).
Perso I use the file function API for storage data.