# Cannot find the object "dbo.course" because it does not exist or you do not have permissions

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6, entity-framework-migrations

I am developing an ASP.NET MVC5 Web Application. I am using Entity Framework 6 for my data storage needs. I am using the code first feature of it with migrations enabled. automatic migrating set to false.

I have two tables that I'm trying to change. The first Table is called course and this is it's model.

```
public class course
{
    [Key]
    public int courseID { get; set; }
    public int categoryID { get; set; }
    public int PaymentOptionsID { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [DisplayName("Course Code")]
    public string courseCode { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [DisplayName("Course Name")]
    public string courseName { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Currency)]
    public decimal price { get; set; }
    [DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
    [DisplayName("Course Description")]
    [StringLength(255, ErrorMessage = "Only a maximum of 255 characters are                                     allowed")]
    public string courseDescription { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [DisplayName("Study Material")]
    public string courseIncludes { get; set; }
    public string courseInfoUrl { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<enrollment> enrollment { get; set; }
    public virtual courseCategory courseCategory { get; set; }
    public virtual PaymentOptions PaymentOptions { get; set; }
}
```

The second table's name is paymentOptions and here is it's model.

```
public class PaymentOptions
{
    [Key]
    public int PaymentOptionsID { get; set; }
    public int courseID { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Payment Options")]
    public string paymentOption {get; set; }
}
```

I have 5 migrations that I've added and they worked fine. Now I'm trying to add the sixth one where I am trying to make the following changes to the tables

```
public class course
{
    [Key]
    public int courseID { get; set; }
    public int categoryID { get; set; }
    public int PaymentOptionsID { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [DisplayName("Course Code")]
    public string courseCode { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [DisplayName("Course Name")]
    public string courseName { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Currency)]
    public decimal price { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [DisplayName("Course Includes")]
    public string courseIncludes { get; set; }
    public string courseInfoUrl { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<enrollment> enrollment { get; set; }
    public virtual courseCategory courseCategory { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<PaymentOptions> PaymentOptions { get; set; }
}    

public class PaymentOptions
{
    [Key]
    public int PaymentOptionsID { get; set; }
    public int courseID { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Payment Options")]
    public string paymentOption {get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<course> course { get; set; }
}
```

When I add the Migration It works fine but as soon as I hit the update-database command all of the sudden I get this error

"Cannot find the object "dbo.course" because it does not exist or you do not have permissions."

This is what the migration looks like.

```
public partial class AddPaymentOptionsagain : DbMigration
{
    public override void Up()
    {
        RenameTable(name: "dbo.course", newName: "PaymentOptionscourse");
        DropForeignKey("dbo.course", "PaymentOptions_PaymentOptionsID", "dbo.PaymentOptions");
        DropIndex("dbo.course", new[] { "PaymentOptions_PaymentOptionsID" });
        AddColumn("dbo.course", "PaymentOptionsID", c => c.Int(nullable: false));
        CreateIndex("dbo.PaymentOptionscourse", "PaymentOptions_PaymentOptionsID");
        CreateIndex("dbo.PaymentOptionscourse", "course_courseID");
        AddForeignKey("dbo.PaymentOptionscourse", "PaymentOptions_PaymentOptionsID", "dbo.PaymentOptions", "PaymentOptionsID", cascadeDelete: true);
        AddForeignKey("dbo.PaymentOptionscourse", "course_courseID", "dbo.course", "courseID", cascadeDelete: true);
        DropColumn("dbo.course", "courseDescription");
        DropColumn("dbo.course", "PaymentOptions_PaymentOptionsID");
    }

    public override void Down()
    {
        AddColumn("dbo.course", "PaymentOptions_PaymentOptionsID", c => c.Int());
        AddColumn("dbo.course", "courseDescription", c => c.String(maxLength: 255));
        DropForeignKey("dbo.PaymentOptionscourse", "course_courseID", "dbo.course");
        DropForeignKey("dbo.PaymentOptionscourse", "PaymentOptions_PaymentOptionsID", "dbo.PaymentOptions");
        DropIndex("dbo.PaymentOptionscourse", new[] { "course_courseID" });
        DropIndex("dbo.PaymentOptionscourse", new[] { "PaymentOptions_PaymentOptionsID" });
        DropColumn("dbo.course", "PaymentOptionsID");
        CreateIndex("dbo.course", "PaymentOptions_PaymentOptionsID");
        AddForeignKey("dbo.course", "PaymentOptions_PaymentOptionsID", "dbo.PaymentOptions", "PaymentOptionsID");
        RenameTable(name: "dbo.PaymentOptionscourse", newName: "course");
    }
}
```

I have read all the questions on stackoverflow, http://forums.asp.net, msdn.microsoft.com › SQL Server and I still can't seem to figure out why this is happening and what I need to do to fix it.

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1136628/cannot-find-the-object-because-it-does-not-exist-or-you-do-not-have-permissions looks relevant

Comment: Never worked with the Entity framework, but in the `Up() ` part, the first step is renaming the table, followed by other steps referencing the old table name. Wouldn't the first step rename the table, thus invalidating all the other lines referencing the old table name?

Comment: Yes your right it seems to be renaming the table which I don't understand why as that is not the changes I have made to my models. I'm not sure if that could be the reason for the error but I'm going to try and change some of the lines of code in the migration to see if it might help. I'm also still new to Entity-framework and I'm only starting to get to grips with it.  @SchmitzIT

Comment: Looks like your changing it to a many-to-many relationship and EF is not understanding. Take a look at the Fluent API where you can specify the relationship. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591620.aspx

Comment: I got it to work, finally. @SteveGreene You where right. The framework did not understand what I was intending to do. It was attempting to rename the course Table instead of Creating a new Table that would be used to hold the keys for the course and paymentOption tables to allow a many to many relationship between the 2 tables. Thank you.

Answer (score 7):

I see the problem in your statements sequence. You are trying to refer to the object after you renamed it.

```
 RenameTable(name: "dbo.course", newName: "PaymentOptionscourse");
    DropForeignKey("dbo.course", "PaymentOptions_PaymentOptionsID", "dbo.PaymentOptions");
    DropIndex("dbo.course", new[] { "PaymentOptions_PaymentOptionsID" });
```

Instead try this

```
 RenameTable(name: "dbo.course", newName: "PaymentOptionscourse");
    DropForeignKey("dbo.PaymentOptionscourse", "PaymentOptions_PaymentOptionsID", "dbo.PaymentOptions");
    DropIndex("dbo.PaymentOptionscourse", new[] { "PaymentOptions_PaymentOptionsID" });
    AddColumn("dbo.PaymentOptionscourse", "PaymentOptionsID", c => c.Int(nullable: false));
    CreateIndex("dbo.PaymentOptionscourse", "PaymentOptions_PaymentOptionsID");
    CreateIndex("dbo.PaymentOptionscourse", "course_courseID");
    AddForeignKey("dbo.PaymentOptionscourse", "PaymentOptions_PaymentOptionsID", "dbo.PaymentOptions", "PaymentOptionsID", cascadeDelete: true);
    AddForeignKey("dbo.PaymentOptionscourse", "course_courseID", "dbo.PaymentOptionscourse", "courseID", cascadeDelete: true);
    DropColumn("dbo.PaymentOptionscourse", "courseDescription");
    DropColumn("dbo.PaymentOptionscourse", "PaymentOptions_PaymentOptionsID");
```

Comment: I'd like to note that this can happen without the developers input, as the DbMigration that Add-Migration generates will order the statements in the incorrect sequence. (NB: EF 6.1.3)