# Which is the true object name for a User-Defined Table Type?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sqldatatypes

In SQL Server, if I create the following type:

```
CREATE TYPE TestType AS TABLE 
(
    [TestTypeId] [int] NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([TestTypeId] ASC) WITH (IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF)
)
```

and then individually query `sys.types` and `sys.objects` for `TestType` I get different results for the type name.

```
SELECT name 
FROM sys.types 
WHERE name LIKE '%TestType%'
```

**Returns**: `TestType`

```
SELECT name 
FROM sys.objects 
WHERE name LIKE '%TestType%'
```

**Returns**: `TT_TestType_66EBFC9C`

Why is this so? What use does the seemingly generated name in `sys.objects` have?

The reason I ask is because an automated process attempted this:

```
GRANT CONTROL ON TT_TestType_66EBFC9C TO user
```

Which produced the error:

> Cannot find the object 'TT_TestType_66EBFC9C', because it does not exist or you do not have permission.

Comment: Isn't it related to this?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1136628/cannot-find-the-object-because-it-does-not-exist-or-you-do-not-have-permissions

Comment: The error isn't the problem, I know I can grant access using `GRANT CONTROL ON TYPE::TestType` but I was wondering why the name `TT_TestType_66EBFC9C` is generated in `sys.objects`