# Amazon RDS regain access in DB

Tags: sql-server, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I was trying to sync one database with another and at the very first tasks of the compare script it had `DROP USER FROM DB` which I didn't see.

So by dropping the user, I cannot access the database any more.

I can access the DB instance but not the specific database. Can I create a new user with full access to access the specific database again?

I tried with this but i get error

```
GRANT ALL ON dbo.myDb TO dbuser;
```

Error is :

```
Msg 15151, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Cannot find the object 'myDb', because it does not exist or you do not have permission.
```

Comment: Hello, solution could be found among these articles https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/duplicate-master-user-mysql/, https://www.techonthenet.com/sql_server/grant_revoke.php, https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-a-new-user-and-grant-permissions-in-mysql

Comment: 2 of your 3 solutions refer to MySQL. I 'm asking for SQL Server. Also i updated the query i run and the error i get when running grant

Comment: Perhaps this might be more helpful based on the error message. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1136628/cannot-find-the-object-because-it-does-not-exist-or-you-do-not-have-permissions

Comment: it's a permission issue, as i said i dropped the userby accident. I'm using AWS RDS and i'm asking if i can create a new user with full access to database.