# Unable to migrate models from django to sql server

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, django, migrate

I'm trying to learn django and have to use sql server as a data base and unable to migrate models using manage.py migrate

I'm using django 2.1.8
Pyodbc
python 3.7.3
I've tried to reinstall django, python and even sql server but it didn't solve the problem.

On running py manage.py migrate, i get the following error

```
    py manage.py migrate
    Operations to perform:

    Apply all migrations: admin, auth, contenttypes, sessions, testApp
    Running migrations:

    Applying contenttypes.0001_initial...Traceback (most recent call last):

    File "C:\Users\Hamza\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 85, in _execute
return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)

    File "C:\Users\Hamza\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\sql_server\pyodbc\base.py", line 546, in execute
return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)

    pyodbc.ProgrammingError: ('42S02', '[42S02] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Cannot find the object "django_content_type" because it does not exist or you do not have permissions. (4902) (SQLExecDirectW)')

    The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "manage.py", line 15, in <module>
execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)

 File "C:\Users\Hamza\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 381, in execute_from_command_line
utility.execute()

File "C:\Users\Hamza\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 375, in execute
self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)

File "C:\Users\Hamza\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 316, in run_from_argv
self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)

File "C:\Users\Hamza\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 353, in execute
output = self.handle(*args, **options)

File "C:\Users\Hamza\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 83, in wrapped
res = handle_func(*args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\Hamza\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\migrate.py", line 203, in handle
fake_initial=fake_initial,

File "C:\Users\Hamza\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 117, in migrate
state = self._migrate_all_forwards(state, plan, full_plan, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)

File "C:\Users\Hamza\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 147, in _migrate_all_forwards
state = self.apply_migration(state, migration, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)

File "C:\Users\Hamza\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 244, in apply_migration
state = migration.apply(state, schema_editor)

File "C:\Users\Hamza\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\migration.py", line 124, in apply
operation.database_forwards(self.app_label, schema_editor, old_state, project_state)

File "C:\Users\Hamza\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\operations\models.py", line 514, in database_forwards
getattr(new_model._meta, self.option_name, set()),

File "C:\Users\Hamza\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\schema.py", line 360, in alter_unique_together
self.execute(self._create_unique_sql(model, columns))

File "C:\Users\Hamza\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\sql_server\pyodbc\schema.py", line 653, in execute
cursor.execute(sql, params)

File "C:\Users\Hamza\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 100, in execute
return super().execute(sql, params)

File "C:\Users\Hamza\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 68, in execute
return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)

File "C:\Users\Hamza\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 77, in _execute_with_wrappers
return executor(sql, params, many, context)

File "C:\Users\Hamza\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 85, in _execute
return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)

File "C:\Users\Hamza\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 89, in __exit__
raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value

File "C:\Users\Hamza\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 85, in _execute
return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)

File "C:\Users\Hamza\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\sql_server\pyodbc\base.py", line 546, in execute
return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: ('42S02', '[42S02] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Cannot find the object "django_content_type" because it does not exist or you do not have permissions. (4902) (SQLExecDirectW)')
```

I expect it to migrate but it gives me this error.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot find the object because it does not exist or you do not have permissions , error in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1136628/cannot-find-the-object-because-it-does-not-exist-or-you-do-not-have-permissions)

Answer (score 1):

Might be a different problem, but I was having the same error. In my case I had run `python manage.py migrate --fake` (per other SO threads) to fix an error I had earlier and django made a record of the migration without actually creating the table. When I ran it again it assumed I was modifying a table that wasn't there.

I eventually solved this by:

1. Manually creating the table in SQL server with all of the correct fields
2. Commenting out the model code from everywhere in the `models.py`
3. `python manage.py makemigrations` to *remove* the fake table from registry
4. `python manage.py migrate` to delete the manual table I just made and update the migrations registry
5. then re-add the table to my `models.py`
6. then re-run `python manage.py makemigrations`
7. `python manage.py migrate` to sync django with SQL server

Comment: what about doing this to undo --fake? `python manage.py migrate --fake myapp 00XX_last_migration`

Comment: Did it work? Honestly, I prefer my solution as it's cleaner. Not that `--fake` is a bad practice, it just seems a little hacky and when I try to use it, I end up with a bunch of mismatched files and I end up power washing everything anyways.